# APEX phone validation

Tags: apex, validation, phone

Hi i want to make a validation on phone fields of Account. The requirement is that the phone number should not contain any letters. It should contain only numbers and symbols like ( ) - , . / \ ... What is the way to achieve this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use REGEX expression that will check your field value:

```
private Boolean isValid(String phone) {
    return Pattern.matches('[0-9(),./\\-]+', phone);
}
```

Comment: Marilia, you are amazing!